# Setting up two RShiny input values for the same value across different tab panels

Tags: shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinyjs

I have an RShiny app using a navBarPage, something like:

```
default_run_date = Sys.Date()
ui <- navbarPage(
  "MyTitle",
  id="mainNavbarPage"
  ),
  tabPanel(
    "Panel1",
    fluidPage(
        dateInput("datePicker1",
                           "Run date:",
                           value = default_run_date,max = Sys.Date())
  ),
  tabPanel(
    "Panel2",
    fluidPage(
        dateInput("datePicker2",
                           "Run date:",
                           value = default_run_date,max = Sys.Date())
  )
)
```

I actually have 5-6 different tabs and I want the user to be able to change a date that applies a setting across all of these tabs. For convenience I want users to have this control when accessing either of two different tabs.

I tried setting up a pair of observers:

```
observeEvent(input$datePicker1,{updateDateInput(session,inputId ="datePicker2",value=input$datePicker1)})
observeEvent(input$datePicker2,{updateDateInput(session,inputId ="datePicker1",value=input$datePicker2)})
```

However each of these events actually triggers the other, resulting in an infinite loop.

Can anyone tell me a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the chosen date in a `reactiveVal`.  Then use `renderUI` to recreate the date pickers whenever the `reactiveVal` changes.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage("MyTitle", id="mainNavbarPage",
                 tabPanel("Panel1", uiOutput("date_ui_1")),
                 tabPanel("Panel2", uiOutput("date_ui_2")))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  # Default starting value for date pickers
  date_chosen <- reactiveVal(Sys.Date())
  
  output$date_ui_1 <- renderUI({
    dateInput("datePicker1",
              "Run date:",
              value = date_chosen(),
              max = Sys.Date())
  })
  
  output$date_ui_2 <- renderUI({
    dateInput("datePicker2",
              "Run date:",
              value = date_chosen(),
              max = Sys.Date())
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$datePicker1, {
    date_chosen(input$datePicker1)
  })
  observeEvent(input$datePicker2, {
    date_chosen(input$datePicker2)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I would not use `renderUI` as the complete `dateInput` has to be rendered on the server side. This causes delays in updating the value, already visible in this toy example. [This blog post](https://appsilon.com/r-shiny-faster-updateinput-css-javascript/) describes why using `updateInput` and doing the change on the client side is faster. You can apply this approach here as following:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage("MyTitle", id="mainNavbarPage",
                 tabPanel("Panel1", dateInput("datePicker1",
                                              "Run date:",
                                              value = Sys.Date(),
                                              max = Sys.Date())),
                 tabPanel("Panel2", dateInput("datePicker2",
                                              "Run date:",
                                              value = Sys.Date(),
                                              max = Sys.Date())))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  # Default starting value for date pickers
  date_chosen <- reactiveVal(Sys.Date())
  
  observeEvent(input$datePicker1, {
    date_chosen(input$datePicker1)
  })
  observeEvent(input$datePicker2, {
    date_chosen(input$datePicker2)
  })
  
  observeEvent(date_chosen(), {
    updateDateInput(session,
                    "datePicker1",
                    value = date_chosen())
    updateDateInput(session,
                    "datePicker2",
                    value = date_chosen())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This is a really great improvement.  Thanks!